# CKReference on CloudKit using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckrecord, ckreference

I have a RecordType `Account` and another one `Friends`.
For `Account` I am setting the `RecordID` on creation of each record and I have a column `Name`.

For Friends I have two columns, `Me` and `MyFriend`. `MyFriend` is a Reference containing the `RecordID` of an Account.

How can I retrieve the Names of Accounts that are my friends?
I need to query Friends to get all the records where `Me` is my `RecordID` and then I need to use these references of the records to get the Names from the Account table.

I have tried the following but I get no results:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Me = %@", recordID)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Friends", predicate: predicate)
publicDB.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        println("Error fetching from Friends table: \(error.description)")
    } else {
        for friend in results {
            var key = friend.objectForKey("MyFriend") as String
            self.publicDB.fetchRecordWithID(CKRecordID(recordName: key), completionHandler: { (record, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    println(error.description)
                } else {
                    self.friends.append(record.objectForKey("Name") as String)
                }
            })
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore)
    }
 }
 dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)`
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Is your 'Me' field of type CKReference? Then the value that you use in the predicate should be of type CKReference. You are now using recordID. I suspect that field is of type recordID is it? Then you should first create a CKReference out of that.

Comment: "Me" is just a String and recordID that I am passing to Me is the record ID -> recordName (which is a String). "MyFriend" is a CKReference for which I want retrieve the respective Account Names.

Comment: If MyFriend is a CKReference, then you should not cast it to a string but to a CKReference and then gets it recordID.recordName

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If MyFriend is a CKReference, then you should not cast it to a string but to a CKReference and then gets it recordID.recordName. So that code will look like this:

```
var myFriend = friend.objectForKey("MyFriend") as CKReference
var key = myFriend.recordID.recordName
```